# Get variables from text File

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file each item is in <> and they are separated by , there is no spaces.

I need to be able to read total number of records and assign this to a variable.

Also I need to assign each item in a row to a variable and the number of that row to a variable. This is so they can be processed later.

I have search the internet but i just seem to be going in circles, any help or source ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?  Reading the file?  Parsing strings?  Creating variables?

Comment: Is there a reason why this file isn't a standard config file?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are not really clear, but i give it a try.

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

class test
{
    public Dictionary<int, String> readAndSortFile()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt");
        Dictionary<int, String> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        int loop = 0;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            dic.Add(loop, sr.ReadLine());
            loop++;
        }
        sr.Close();

        return dic;
    }
}
```

your result should look like this:

```
[0] {[0, <a>]}  
[1] {[1, <b>]}
[2] {[2, <c>]}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get file like this

```
string file = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(folderName), "*.txt");

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
// to read all content of this file you can use -      
File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName)
```

and after this you can use Dictionary to save your data and then you can use it later.
You can read here - http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/dictionary.htm